# Does USB have some kind of current cutter that cuts the current for safety?

Tags: usb, protection, circuit-protection, usb-hub

I accidentally got 24V into the GND on my Arduino and then the USB shut off - but not all of them. When I restarted my computer, then all USB shut off and they are not giving out any current. Notice that the GND of the 24V power source was connected with the GND of the USB. They have the same voltage potential.

This issue had happen be before and then I fixed it by upgrading the BIOS in my computer.

Now I'm facing the same issue again with the latest BIOS software.

Can the BIOS lock the USB current or what makes the USB current go off if the USB got a high voltage peak?

Comment: Yes, a computer motherboard may have usb overcurrent and or over voltage protection. But most companies don't go that far to protect the usb ports. Some if not most have them tied directly to the power supply.

Comment: @Passerby this is(was) an expensive computer and not cheap stuff. If the USB port break, why did even the hub and all other USB 2.0, USB 3.0 shut down then?

Comment: I don't believe the BIOS can (nor should) permanently disable USB.  I think what you experienced was something else; perhaps a reset of all the devices got it working.  But it is highly unlikely that a BIOS update "enabled" USB again.  In my experience, injecting sufficient voltage into a USB port is usually damaging to the USB hardware, if not fatal for the computer.

Comment: @rdtsc According to the support, they say it's a software issue. Hold reset for 30 seconds when the computer is powered off. Need to try that.

Comment: @rdtsc Well, in this case. I did not give the USB 24V. The GND of the Arduino got 24V and the power suppy GND was connected to the Arduino as well. The Arduino survived. No burt circuits. No smell at all from the computer.

Comment: `The GND of the Arduino got 24V` ... probably not ... where was the power supply GND connected?

Comment: Its working now. Reinstalled Windows.

Comment: I think this is a textbook definition of "red herring."  I.e., you think the issue is X, when it is actually Y. Reinstalling Windows was likely unnecessary and probably created even more confusion. Since it is impossible to determine what happened without solid evidence, I am voting to close this question. Next time something like this happens, it needs to be backed by a schematic and the exact fault cause (not a guess or assumption.) This means you must be more diligent and precise in your setup and testing methodologies; otherwise you may continue to experience "red herrings." Best wishes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the sort of thing that might require a new motherboard. modern USB ports may be tolerant of overloads, but externally applied voltage is another matter.

This is why I use a USB isolator when fiddling around with such things. Better to wreck a $50 isolator than an expensive motherboard.

Comment: Yes. But I don't think the motherborad is brokend. This has happen before and I fixed it by resetting everything and update. So my question is if an USB have some kind of protection. I have two kinds of USB. USB 2.0 and USB 3.0. The USB 3.0 stoppend worked directly. All of them. But the USB 2.0 worked until I reboted the computer. So I assume that the computer locking the USB or just "cut the GND" so no current can flow inside the computer.

Comment: A powered hub is a lot cheaper than an isolator

Comment: @ScottSeidman It's weird, because the hub did also die. But when I plug it into another computer, it works. It feels like my computer tell the hub "lock down" when I plugin the hub into my computer.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Yes, but an isolator is much safer.

Comment: `It feels like my computer tell the hub "lock down"` ... the computer is not telling the hub anything ... that is probably the problem

Comment: @jsotola But the hub don't give out current from its USB ports.

Comment: @jsotola i reinstalled Windows. Now it's working